# Unmet dependencies installing with Features with fields, paragraphs, blocks and content types

Tags: 8, features

I have defined several content types, paragraphs, and views for these content types and the idea was to define different features to export and import these content types. I had defined different features for each content type but when I tried to install on a site the Core feature there were a lot of dependencies unmet.

Although is not ideal, I tried to export everything in just one feature, but when I installed it again more dependencies were met. For blocks, fields and paragraphs. Trying to find out what the problem was I opened one of the yml files: field.field.node.producto.body.yml and one of the dependencies is - node.type.producto and this is a content type that doesn't exist but in theory is included in the feature.

This is the message that appears when I try to install the feature:

*Incapaz de instalar All, block.block.lemonadmin_views_block__servicios_block_servicios, block.block.views_block__servicios_block_servicios, block.block.web_views_block__servicios_block_servicios, core.base_field_override.node.producto.promote, core.base_field_override.node.producto.title, core.entity_form_display.node.producto.default, core.entity_view_display.node.article.teaser_2, core.entity_view_display.node.producto.default, core.entity_view_display.node.producto.teaser, core.entity_view_display.node.proyecto.teaser, core.entity_view_display.node.team.default, core.entity_view_display.node.team.teaser, core.entity_view_display.node.team.teaser_2, core.entity_view_display.paragraph.card.default, core.entity_view_display.paragraph.foto.default, core.entity_view_display.paragraph.photo_banner.default, core.entity_view_display.paragraph.texto_con_foto.default, field.field.node.producto.body, field.field.node.producto.field_content_en_bloques_product, field.field.node.producto.field_texto_thumbnail, field.field.node.producto.field_thumbnail_producto, field.field.node.producto.field_tipo_de_producto, field.field.paragraph.foto.field_formato_imagen, field.field.paragraph.texto_con_foto.field_formato_imagen, language.content_settings.node.producto tiene dependencias no encontradas.*

With Drupal 7 it was really easy to import Features, what steps should I follow to achieve what I want? I'm getting mad with this issue.